# My ajax call in module not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, ajax

My call is going to controller but not to the block.I am giving the code related with problem. 
I am trying to make a product zoom module which fetch big image of product from database when user click on any product box.I am doing this on category pages not on the product page.if anything is needed please comment.

My js method is below:

```
function displayData(elem){
    var pro_id = jQuery(elem).attr("id");
    jQuery(".nzoom-div2").fadeIn("fast");
    var pd = $j("#nzoom-hide"+pro_id).val();
    var img_data = "pid="+pd;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('zoomer/ajax/index'); ?>",
        type: "GET",
        cache:false,
        data: img_data,
        dataType:"text",
        error:errorhandler,
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(img_data);
            jQuery('.nzoom-div2-inner1 img').attr('src', result);
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
class Test1_Zoomer_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

public function indexAction() {
Mage::log('zoomer controller', null,'zoomer3.log');
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
}
```

}

Layout file zoomer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">     
    <zoomer_ajax_index>
 <reference name="content">
      <block type="zoomer/zoomer" name="root" output="toHtml" template="zoomer/zoomer.phtml" />
 </reference>
 </zoomer_ajax_index>

 </layout>
```

Block Zoomer.php

```
  class Test1_Zoomer_Block_Zoomer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
/* protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('zoomer/zoomer.phtml');
} 
*/

public function methodBlock() {
    Mage::log('zoom block', null,'zoomer3.log');
  return "working code";
}

   /*protected function _toHtml() {
    return parent::_toHtml();
   }*/



}
```

Template zoomer/zoomer.phtml

```
<?php methodBlock(); ?>
```

Config.xml inside the etc/

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Test1_Zoomer>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Test1_Zoomer>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <zoomer>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Test1_Zoomer</module>
          <frontName>zoomer</frontName>
        </args>
      </zoomer>
    </routers>
    <global>
    <blocks>
    <test1_zoomer>
    <class>
    Test1_Zoomer_Block
    </class>
    </test1_zoomer>
    </blocks>
    </global>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <zoomer>
          <file>zoomer.xml</file>
        </zoomer>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your layout xml so that it does not use content but instead add items directly to the root name.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">     
    <zoomer_ajax_index>
        <block type="zoomer/zoomer" name="root" output="toHtml" template="zoomer/zoomer.phtml" />
    </zoomer_ajax_index>
</layout>
```

This change should then mean that you simply get the block and nothing else returned by the ajax call.

You may also want to update your controller so that if does not add the default layout handles and so does not show the header and footer of the page.

```
$this->loadLayout(false);
```

Comment: I tried this but not working.Response is coming but only Theme's header and footer html.

Comment: Does layout file location matter? It put the layout in base theme now.